# Python: what is "@main.result_callback()"?

Tags: python, click

i'm trying to understand how [that](https://github.com/amazon-research/patchcore-inspection/blob/main/bin/load_and_evaluate_patchcore.py) python code works. In particular i'm referring to that part (from line 27):

```
def main(**kwargs):
    pass

@main.result_callback()
def run(methods, results_path, gpu, seed, save_segmentation_images):
    methods = {key: item for (key, item) in methods}
    ...
```

What i don't understand is where the parameter **methods** is taken from. All the other parameters are command line parameters obtained through the library "click", as you can see in the complete code linked before.
I'm sorry if the question is generic but i can't find anything related to this **@main.result_callback()** thing used here. I don't even understand if it's from "click" or not

Comment: You didn't copy decorators of `main`. Without decorators, this will not work, obviously. And yes, the `.result_callback` has to be from `click` because `main` itself doesn't have it and all decorators are from `click`. | Docs of `.result_callback` - https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/?highlight=result_callback#click.MultiCommand.result_callback

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part here is what you did not show:

```
@click.group(chain=True)
...
def main(**kwargs):
    pass
```

The main function is wrapped by a decorator and becomes a `click.MultiCommand`. This `MultiCommand` can have callback functions and they are defined by the `.result_callback()` decorator.

See the [documentation on `result_callback`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.MultiCommand.result_callback) for more details.